# Browser opens blank screen, ignores url

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm making a custom browser, following a tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z-5bZ8EoKu4
I have coded everything to the T, and for some reason when I open the browser, even though I have `self.browser.setUrl(QUrl('http://duckduckgo.com'))` set for the default url to open to. How can I fix this?

The code:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.browser = QWebEngineView()
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl('http://duckduckgo.com'))
        self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)
        self.showMaximized()

        # navbar
        navbar = QToolBar()
        self.addToolBar(navbar)

        back_btn = QAction('Back', self)

        back_btn.triggered.connect(self.browser.back)
        navbar.addAction(back_btn)

        forward_btn = QAction('Forward', self)
        forward_btn.triggered.connect(self.browser.forward)
        navbar.addAction(forward_btn)

        reload_btn = QAction('Reload', self)
        reload_btn.triggered.connect(self.browser.reload)
        navbar.addAction(reload_btn)

        home_btn = QAction('home', self)
        home_btn.triggered.connect(self.navigate_home)
        navbar.addAction(home_btn)

        self.url_bar = QLineEdit()
        self.url_bar.returnPressed.connect(self.navigate_to_url)
        navbar.addWidget(self.url_bar)

    def navigate_home(self):
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl('http://duckduckgo.com'))

    def navigate_to_url(self):
        url = self.url_bar.text()
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl(url))


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
QApplication.setApplicationName('quicksearch')
window = MainWindow()
app.exec_()"
```

Comment: What happens if you use the "navigate home" button?

Comment: @mkrieger1 It still is a blank screen, like, all of the buttons show up just fine, and work. The navbar also accepts urls, and *tries* to process it, but fails and stays white.

Comment: So your question is why `setUrl` does not work at all, not just why it doesn't work initially.

Comment: Are you in a venv? Are you using a proxy? Are you using virtualization? What OS? Did you try to run the program from a terminal or prompt to see any useful output/debug info? What version of Qt *and* PyQt are you using?

Comment: @musicamante I believe I am in a venv, No, I am not using a proxy, No I am not using a virtualization, I'm on linux lite, I believe I am using pyqt5.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Yes, It does not work at all.

Comment: @quicktest Sorry, but you need to be more specific. 1. Are you in a venv or not? 2. What linux lite version? Also, did you recently update something? 3. We already know that you're using PyQt5, we need to know the *exact version* of *both* PyQt *and* Qt (their minimum version number don't always match). 4. What about the output when running from a terminal?

Comment: @musicamante Ok, My apologies. These are my versions
Qt version: 5.15.2
PyQt version: 5.15.7
I am in venv
While my fork is linux lite, my os is UBUNTU 22.04.1
and as for terminal output, I'm not sure how to run my code in terminal